# Android GetView

Tags: android

I have two gridView, two ArrayList data and two differen ArrayAdapter, but why I see the same data both of them - "2"?

```
data1.add("1");
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.item3, R.id.editText1, data1) {
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item3, null);
        }
        final String theData = getItem(position);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.setText(theData);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(position));                   
        return convertView;
    }
};
gvMain1.setAdapter(listAdapter1);

data2.add("2");
ArrayAdapter<String>  listAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  R.layout.item3, R.id.editText1, data2) {
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item3, null);
        }
        final String theData = getItem(position);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText.setText(theData);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(position));                   
        return convertView;
    }
};
gvMain2.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
```

Comment: I does not seem like the problem is in this particular code snippet. A little more code would be helpful.
Btw: Why don't you make a proper class for the array adapter instead of just copy-pasting the code?

Comment: you'll have to more clear about what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create class:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> names;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> names) {
        super(context, R.layout.item3, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        public EditText editText;
    }

   public ArrayList<String> getData()
   {
       return this.names;
   }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item3, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.editText  = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.editText.setText(names.get(position));
        holder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(position));    
        return rowView;
    }
    class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher 
    {
        private int position;

        public MyTextWatcher(int position) 
        {
                this.position = position;
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
        {
            names.set(position, s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) 
        {
        }

   }
}
```

And call it from my activity:

```
 final MyArrayAdapter myAd1=new MyArrayAdapter(this,data1);
final MyArrayAdapter myAd2=new MyArrayAdapter(this,data2);
     gvMain1.setAdapter(myAd1);
     gvMain2.setAdapter(myAd2);
```